# different jquery ui buttons at the same time

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a proper way to have 2 differently styled jquery ui buttons on the same page?

I am able to copy css around for the second button but there are a lot of different !important styles that I keep needing to add a second !important after the first in order to change the style.

for ex:

```
 .ui-state-active {
    background:none !important;
    background-color:#E1E1E1 !important; 
    color:#000 !important;
 }
```

I will then have to go and add right after (and it needs to be after

```
 .new-theme.ui-state-active {
    background:none !important;
    background-color:red !important; 
    color:#000 !important; 
 }
```

the problem is these important styles are all over for each state so I have to mind where they go. Is this normal or is this usually handled a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using an older version of jQuery UI that requires you to use !important to override their styles?  Newer version have [fixed this: Use of !important in jquery-ui.css should be avoided](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8396).

If you can/are using a newer version, try getting rid of !important and instead rely on [selector specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to get your desired results.

Comment: This is a version that came with oscommerce so it is very very likely this is the case. I will upgrade to the new version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [jqueryui-speciffic css](http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/). Except difficulties with different button stylings, there may be performance problems while rendering larger amounts of buttons.
[This resource](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/styling_buttons_and_toolbars_with_the_jquery_ui_css_framework/) is relatively old but I found it very valuable while using jqueryui css.